# How to add a popup textbox for submitting a message - Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, toolkit

Shame I have to install another toolkit, but this seems to be pretty useful: [Coding4Fun InputPrompt](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/coding4fun-toolkit-for-wp7-overview-and-getting-started).

I am having an issue with it though:
There only seems to be functionality for triggering an event when the input is 'completed' without being able to differentiate between whether the tick is tapped or if the cross is tapped.

Rushed into asking for help unnecessarily there. Found a solution, will post below.

---

Original question:

Users of my application can currently submit messages which they do by tapping on a textbox and typing in the message and then tapping send.
I want to make this cleaner by not having a permanent textbox for this and instead have users tap on a button on the application bar along the button which brings up the keyboard along with a textbox to type into, and when users tap submit the textbox and keyboard disappear again.

I can't see any way of creating a popup with a textbox in it, so how would I do this?

I'm using the WP Toolkit already for a messagebox with a ListPicker inside, by even this toolkit seemingly has no way of adding a textbox.

Comment: Usually you create a new page for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame I have to install another toolkit., but this seems to do the trick just fine: [Coding4Fun InputPrompt](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/coding4fun-toolkit-for-wp7-overview-and-getting-started).

They've added `input.IsCancelVisible = true` to add a cancel button and then use `e.PopUpResult.ToString() == "Ok"` within the input_completed method to only submit when the tick button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your trying to do is even possible.  However, what you could do is have a `Parent Form` which contains your ideal *Interface*.  Within this *Parent* you could create an `Event Handler` that is listening for a response.

Then when it comes to that `Textbox` it actually creates a `Child Form` or `Page`.  Which they can input their value into.  Then the page automatically closes, which then the `Event Handler` will already know the change for you to manipulate with the rest of your Logic.

As mentioned above, normally you would go to another page.  I don't know if my solution is viable, but it does accomplish your goal.  I'd recommend possibly refactoring your interface so that it makes it slightly more elegant.  That way your logic handles it more elegant as well.

Hope that helps.